# Ollydbg:how to let Olly remember a breakpoint for next run

Tags: ollydbg, debugging, breakpoint

I'm a Olly newbie... whenever I set a breakpoint at an address and found I need to restart the target program, the previously set breakpoints are all removed. Is there anyway to let Olly to remember the breakpoints for certain executable, so that everytime when I want to debug that executable, the previously set breakpoints are still there?

Comment: What version of OllyDbg are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of OllyDbg v1.

There are a couple of plugins designed to fix this in v1 (such as [Breakpoint Manager](http://www.openrce.org/downloads/details/168/Breakpoint_Manager)), but the better solution is to upgrade to [OllyDbg v2](http://www.ollydbg.de/odbg201.zip).